# Ripple animation showing circle one after another

Tags: css, css-animations, ripple-effect

Hi there I want to give this effect to my logo

[image]

but somehow I am stuck can you help me please? I want the circles to be show one in after another but only when shown the fourth circle only then the efect can end. Sorry for my english. Please help

```css
html,
body {
  color: #2E4453;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: #D1C4E9;
}

.open-dev-radar {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.open-dev-badge {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  /* padding: 15px; */
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34);
}

.gt-dev {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.gt-dev:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 1px rgba(103, 58, 182, 0.74);
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner, rgba(103, 58, 182, 0) 52%, rgba(103, 58, 182, 0.62) 100%);
  background-image: radial-gradient( circle farthest-corner, rgba(103, 58, 182, 0) 52%, rgba(103, 58, 182, 0.62) 100%);
  -webkit-animation-duration: 9s;
  animation-duration: 9s;
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  animation-name: pulse;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

.gt-dev:nth-child(4) {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

.gt-dev:nth-child(3) {
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
}

.gt-dev:nth-child(3):after {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.gt-dev:nth-child(2) {
  width: 270px;
  height: 270px;
}

.gt-dev:nth-child(2):after {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.gt-dev:nth-child(1) {
  width: 370px;
  height: 370px;
}

.gt-dev:nth-child(1):after {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Ripple Animation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="gt-dev"></div>
  <div class="gt-dev"></div>
  <div class="gt-dev"></div>
  <div class="gt-dev"></div>
  <div class="open-dev-badge"><img src="Loader.svg"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far. It would help us if we can see the problem for ourselves so include a working snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: yes but i want to show first  circle stop the efect so the circle do not fade or go away then show the second stop effect show third circle stop efect and Then when the fourth circle is shown all the circles then fade or go away.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a slightly different approach.

As the circles are purely for decoration, not containing information that needs to be interpreted e.g. by a screen reader, I'd have the logo contained entirely within one element and put the background overall color on that element and the circles on its before pseudo element.

Then use a CSS animation to draw the circles with radial-gradient backgrounds one by one.

In this snippet the colors required are defined as CSS variables col1... so you can change them easily if needed. The animation works by setting the colors in the radial gradient background one by one.

```css
.logo {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  background-color: #303030;
}

.logo::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  --col1: #a5bc1f;
  --col2: #99ae21;
  --col3: #707d28;
  --col4: #4a4f2d;
  --c1: var(--col1);
  --c2: var(--col2);
  --c3: var(--col3);
  --c4: var(--col4);
  background-image: radial-gradient(var(--c1) 0 10%, var(--c2) 10% 20%, var(--c3) 20% 30%, var(--c4) 30% 40%, transparent 40% 100%);
}

.logo::before {
  animation: ripple 4s linear;
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    --c2: transparent;
    --c3: transparent;
    --c4: transparent;
    --c1: var(--col1);
  }
  33.33% {
    --c2: var(--col2);
  }
  66.66% {
    --c3: var(--col3);
  }
  100% {
    --c4: var(--col4);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
```

Note: you will want to change the %s in the radial gradient to get the effect you want (or change to px if you want exactly the same widths on any viewport dimensions).

UPDATE: from subsequent comments it transpires that the problem is actually simpler than the solution given above. Rather than each ring appearing in a step, it is required that the rings grow til they reach the required size, then the next ring grows.

We can get this effect by having the multi ring background on a pseudo element all the time (no need to change it dynamically like in the above) and simply increase its size from zero so the rings appear to grow in a continuous way.

```css
.logo {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  --col1: #a5bc1f;
  --col2: #99ae21;
  --col3: #707d28;
  --col4: #4a4f2d;
}

.logo::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-image: radial-gradient(var(--col1) 0 10vmin, var(--col2) 10vmin 20vmin, var(--col3) 20vmin 30vmin, var(--col4) 30vmin 40vmin, transparent 40vmin 100vmin);
  animation: ripple 4s linear 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index;
  -1;
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100vmin;
    height: 100vmin;
  }
}

.logo::before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #303030;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
```

Comment: thank you very much. may i ask you if i want to add the logo in the center and still want to show the four circle how can i do it ?

Comment: Just put the logo as the background image on the .logo div before as the first part of its background image with background-position center and whatever background-size you want.

Comment: thank you very much @A Haworth

Comment: and if i want to give an effect so they can appear with fade so with a beautiful effect?

Comment: Sorry I don’t fully understand. Do you want each ring to fade in rather than appear instantly? Have. You tried animating opacity?

Comment: yes correct i want them to fade in. Nope i havent tried. I tried other effects with keyframes to fade in but does not work maybe i am doing it wrong

Comment: Can you help me  please?

Comment: Hi, I think I need to understand more about what you need, Do you mean each ring to fade in (opacity 0 to 1), or do you mean each ring to grow to its final width?

Comment: so the second meaning each ring to grow to the final width. and very sorry for my english